# Can IMSI catchers detect encrypted communications?

Tags: phone, smartphone

I would like to know if IMSI catchers can detect encrypted communications in general. Anyone got experience with that?

Thanks

Comment: "catch"? as in, decrypt?

Comment: Yes, by artificially downgrading the encryption level, as shown here:  https://security.stackexchange.com/questions/157316/gsm-encryption-suppression/160390#160390

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes they can because they can read any datastream they capture. They cannot necessarily decrypt it.

So the agent with the IMSI catcher knows that there is an encrypted communication, but he cannot get the plain text (in general).